# Getting unknown error when trying to run cypher query

Tags: browser, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to run this query :

```
MERGE (pisrael:country {_id:'israel'})
MERGE (pisrael)-[:city]->(pisrael_pyafo:city {_id:'yafo'})
MERGE (pisrael_pyafo)-[:region]->(pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire:region {_id:'bedfordshire'})
MERGE (pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire)-[:street]->(pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_phoppecircle:street {_id:'hoppecircle'})
MERGE (pisrael_pyafo)-[:region]->(pisrael_pyafo_pavon:region {_id:'avon'})
MERGE (pisrael_pyafo_pavon)-[:street]->(pisrael_pyafo_pavon_plaurycliff:street {_id:'laurycliff'})
MERGE (pisrael)-[:city]->(pisrael_phaifa:city {_id:'haifa'})
MERGE (pisrael_phaifa)-[:region]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon:region {_id:'avon'})
MERGE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon)-[:street]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges:street {_id:'dougridges'})
MERGE (pisrael_pyafo_pavon)-[:street]->(pisrael_pyafo_pavon_pdougridges:street {_id:'dougridges'})
MERGE (pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire)-[:street]->(pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_ppercyneck:street {_id:'percyneck'})
MERGE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon)-[:street]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff:street {_id:'laurycliff'})
MERGE (pisrael_phaifa)-[:region]->(pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire:region {_id:'bedfordshire'})
MERGE (pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire)-[:street]->(pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_phoppecircle:street {_id:'hoppecircle'})
MERGE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon)-[:street]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck:street {_id:'percyneck'})
MERGE (pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire)-[:street]->(pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_pdougridges:street {_id:'dougridges'})
MERGE (pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire)-[:street]->(pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_plaurycliff:street {_id:'laurycliff'})
MERGE (pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire)-[:street]->(pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_ppercyneck:street {_id:'percyneck'})
MERGE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon)-[:street]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle:street {_id:'hoppecircle'})
MERGE (pisrael_pyafo_pavon)-[:street]->(pisrael_pyafo_pavon_ppercyneck:street {_id:'percyneck'})
MERGE (pisrael_pyafo_pavon)-[:street]->(pisrael_pyafo_pavon_phoppecircle:street {_id:'hoppecircle'})


WITH pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_phoppecircle, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_plaurycliff, pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_pdougridges, pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_ppercyneck, pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff, pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_phoppecircle, pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck, pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_pdougridges, pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_plaurycliff, pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_ppercyneck, pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_ppercyneck, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_phoppecircle
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c2:circle {_id:2})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c2)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c2_p1:post {_id:1})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c19:circle {_id:19})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c15:circle {_id:15})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c15)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c15_p2:post {_id:2})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c5:circle {_id:5})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c5)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c5_p1:post {_id:1})
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c22:circle {_id:22})
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c23:circle {_id:23})
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c24:circle {_id:24})
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c25:circle {_id:25})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges.circle_count=25
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c2_p1)-[:comment]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c2_p1_c1:comment {_id:1})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c2_p1.comment_count=1
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c19)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c19_p1:post {_id:1})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c19.post_count=1
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c15_p2)-[:comment]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c15_p2_c1:comment {_id:1})
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c15_p2)-[:comment]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c15_p2_c2:comment {_id:2})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c15_p2.comment_count=2
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c5_p1)-[:comment]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c5_p1_c2:comment {_id:2})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_pdougridges_c5_p1.comment_count=2


WITH pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_phoppecircle, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_plaurycliff, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_pdougridges, pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_ppercyneck, pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff, pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_phoppecircle, pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck, pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_pdougridges, pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_plaurycliff, pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_ppercyneck, pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_ppercyneck, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_phoppecircle
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle_c2:circle {_id:2})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle_c2)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle_c2_p1:post {_id:1})
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle_c10:circle {_id:10})
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle_c11:circle {_id:11})
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle_c12:circle {_id:12})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle.circle_count=12
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle_c2_p1)-[:comment]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle_c2_p1_c1:comment {_id:1})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_phoppecircle_c2_p1.comment_count=1


WITH pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_phoppecircle, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_plaurycliff, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_pdougridges, pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_ppercyneck, pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff, pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_phoppecircle, pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck, pisrael_pyafo_pbedfordshire_pdougridges, pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_plaurycliff, pisrael_phaifa_pbedfordshire_ppercyneck, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_ppercyneck, pisrael_pyafo_pavon_phoppecircle
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c14:circle {_id:14})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c2:circle {_id:2})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c2)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c2_p1:post {_id:1})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c3:circle {_id:3})
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c19:circle {_id:19})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff.circle_count=19
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c14)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c14_p1:post {_id:1})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c14.post_count=1
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c2_p1)-[:comment]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c2_p1_c1:comment {_id:1})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c2_p1.comment_count=1
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c3)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c3_p2:post {_id:2})
SET pisrael_phaifa_pavon_plaurycliff_c3.post_count=2


WITH pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c1:circle {_id:1})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c1)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c1_p1:post {_id:1})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c1)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c1_p3:post {_id:3})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c5:circle {_id:5})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c5)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c5_p2:post {_id:2})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c8:circle {_id:8})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c4:circle {_id:4})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c4)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c4_p1:post {_id:1})
WITH pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c7:circle {_id:7})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c3:circle {_id:3})
MATCH (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c3)-[:post]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c3_p1:post {_id:1})
CREATE (pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck)-[:circle]->(pisrael_phaifa_pavon_ppercyneck_c17:circle {_id:17})
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: Found no solution for block with size 8,
Vector() were the selected candidates from the table IDPPlanTable(numberOfPlans=63, largestSolved=6)
```

You can try run it with `EXPLAIN` and you'll get the same error (if not then I think it is a bug or something)
Here is the opened issue in github: 
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12212

 
**UPDATE**
I tried to run it on a better computer and it didn't give any errors, but I got the error when I tried with a bigger cypher.

Comment: Is there more to this database?  You start matching `:circle`, `:post`, etc.,  relationships before they are created.

Comment: Yes I start with adding circles then next transaction circles and posts (posts in already added circles before) and then the last transactions (that I copied the cypher from) add circles,posts and comments, the problem is sometimes the third transaction does not work and give the error above and sometimes it does works, but all this start to happen after I changed the statements order in the cypher, now I match all the needed nodes and do changes to it after, before I was matching and do changes immediately and never seen this error, that is what makes me confused: bug or me missing something.

Comment: You are using [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) in a possibly dangerous way (and it may be related in some way to your issue). `MERGE` will create the specified pattern unless the *entire pattern* does not yet exist. For example, in your second `MERGE`, even if there already is a "yafo" `city` node, `MERGE` will create a new "yafo" `city` node if the existing one does not have a `city` relationship to `pisrael`. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: I have index on _id, the cypher worked perfect till the last change which is not related to `MERGE`

Comment: Indexing is unrelated to my last comment. Your Cypher looks like it is repeating a lot of patterns. It should probably be refactored to take advantage of [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/). For instance see https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-create-multiple-nodes-with-properties for an example of how to create multiple nodes with parameters.